# DataColumn Extended Properties

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

Hi I have a datatable which some of the data requires formatting (mainly for exporting) I decided the best way to change the data in the datatable would to be use an extension class passing through a key value pair. The key being the column name and the value the formatting required.

Since then some of our columns can have delimitered data, I am trying to avoid change my key value pair from column name/formatting to column name/object. While researching I came across extended properties, this sounds like exactly what i want, however I cannot seem t get this working.

```
datatable.column["columnName"].ExtendedProperties.Add("Delimiter", ",");
```

I keep getting object is not set to an instance error, but all documentation does not require an instance. I then tried the following:

```
DataColumn dc = datatable.column["columnName"];
dc.ExtendedProperties.Add("Delimiter", ",");
```

but I still get the same error, anyone else know how to use the extended properties, the MS documentation is not clear at all or there is something missing not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Is dc actually set to a DataColumn when stepped through or is it null? Sounds like you’re trying to access ExtendedProperties on a null object.

Comment: Hi yes dc has picked up my column, i have triple checked this as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks to Troy Mac1ure I again stepped through my code and it turns out in the complexity of my code I am using the wrong datatable. I have corrected this and it is all working as expected.

Thank you